# Group by and aggregate the values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have following dataframe in python

```
    meddra_id   meddra_label              soc       cross_ref                       soc_term
2   10000081    Abdominal pain            10017947  http://snomed.info/id/21522001  Gastrointestinal disorders
3   10017999    Gastrointestinal pain     10017947  http://snomed.info/id/21522001  Gastrointestinal disorders
15  10000340    Abstains from alcohol     10041244  http://snomed.info/id/105542008 Social circumstances
35  10001022    Acute psychosis           10037175  http://snomed.info/id/69322001  Psychiatric disorders
36  10061920    Psychotic disorder        10037175  http://snomed.info/id/69322001  Psychiatric disorders
```

I would like to aggregate the values in 'meddra_id, meddra_label, soc and soc_term' columns using group by another column 'cross_ref' (and exclude the rows where there is single 'meddra_id' associated to 'cross_ref').

The expected output is:

```
meddra_id           meddra_label                           soc      cross_ref                       soc_term
10000081,10017999   Abdominal pain,Gastrointestinal pain   10017947 http://snomed.info/id/21522001  Gastrointestinal disorders
10001022,10061920   Acute psychosis,Psychotic disorder     10037175 http://snomed.info/id/69322001  Psychiatric disorders
```

I am trying following lines of code.

```
df_terms = df.groupby('cross_ref').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['meddra_id', 'meddra_label', 'soc', 'soc_term'], keep="first")

#aggregate the values
df_terms = df_terms.groupby('cross_ref')['meddra_id', 'meddra_label', 'soc', 'soc_term'].agg(' , '.join).reset_index()
```

When I try to aggegate the value, the column 'soc_term' is not showed up in the new dataframe (df_terms)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg` to join the values in the different columns:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('cross_ref') #group as you did
df_filtered = df_grouped.filter(lambda g: len(g['meddra_id'].unique()) > 1) # filter it for single values

df_aggregated = df_filtered.groupby('cross_ref').agg({
    'meddra_id': ', '.join,
    'meddra_label': ', '.join,
    'soc': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)), # convert float values to strings
    'soc_term': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)) # convert float values to strings
}).reset_index() #aggregate to join values in the different columns via a comma
```

Comment: I get this error when i run the aggregation.  `TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it by mapping the values properly.  @rshar

Comment: Is there a way to get unique values after aggregation as the current aggregation has duplicates? Thanks

Comment: That is a separate question. There are various approaches on how to clean it down to unique values. (e.g. iterate over the list and clean it or e.g. use `drop_duplicates`)

Comment: Just a small modification to get the unique values.
`df_aggregated = df_filtered.groupby('cross_ref').agg({
    'meddra_id': lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)),
    'meddra_label': lambda x: ', '.join(set(x)),
    'soc': lambda x: ', '.join(set(map(str, x))), 
    'soc_term': lambda x: ', '.join(set(map(str, x))) 
}).reset_index() `

Comment: True! Good approach from your end. Do you want me to edit it into my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250189/discussion-between-rshar-and-j-m-arnold).